# How to remove decimals in barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This is my working environment right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnL1B.png)

What should I add to my code to remove those mixed numbers -or they're just decimals, it confuses me-written in bars and label them with integers instead?

Thank you

Comment: What about [`round(x, 0)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Round) or `trunc(x, …)`?

Comment: You have two `geom_text` calls that are overplotting each other...

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the round() function: round(x, digits = 0)